# Potential bug in geiser installation when using it with guile

Tags: scheme

I'm using Emacs 26.0.50.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3. I built it from source.

I recently installed Guile 2.2.0 by also building it from source. I can successfully interact with it from the command line with no problem. The sample file I am working with taken from the Guile manual and is as follows:

```
(define (make-serial-number-generator)
  (let ((current-serial-number 0))
    (lambda ()
      (set! current-serial-number (+ current-serial-number 1))
      current-serial-number)))

(define entry-sn-generator (make-serial-number-generator))
```

Then, I installed Geiser 0.9 from melpa-stable. After trying to go through the Geiser manual, I get stuck pretty quickly. In particular, when I attempt any of the following commands...

```
M-x run-geiser <ret> guile <ret>
M-x run-guile
M-x geiser-mode
```

...I get the following error:

```
apply: Invalid function: (lambda (&rest) geiser-guile-case-sensitive-p)
```

I can't see how to work around this problem and I don't know enough to be able to dig deeper. Everything is the stock setup, so I'm a little baffled that there is no mention of this elsewhere.

Can anybody provide me with any suggestions?

Comment: Report a bug at Geiser's bugtracker. This isn't one. Also, turn this into a full backtrace with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before triggering it.

Comment: Thanks. The `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` was pretty much exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Relevant issues: https://github.com/jaor/geiser/pull/195, https://github.com/jaor/geiser/issues/211, https://github.com/jaor/geiser/issues/207

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to upvote this, but this stymied me for too long. Same config, Emacs 26, geiser from MELPA stable. The bug is always some version of

```
apply: Invalid function: (lambda (&rest) ...)
```

Simply upgrade to the latest version on MELPA, thanks for figuring this out.

Comment: I think just summarizing the patch at https://github.com/jaor/geiser/pull/195 should make this into a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being to use the latest version from melpa unstable.